# No mobs spawning

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been playing a new Minecraft server on PS4 for a couple days now, I’ve got a few things built and organised, but now I have no enemies spawning what so ever even in mob spawners. I only have 30 cows, I also have my turtles despawning in a 10x10 fenced off area, what’s going on, is there a setting I may have changed accidentally with out realising.

Comment: what difficulty are you on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: why didn't you accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the server is on peaceful difficulty, where all enemies but the Ender Dragon do not spawn and if they do (with spawn eggs, commands, e.t.c) they get immediately deleted

As with the turtles, it is a bug. It is mentioned in [MCPE-70664](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-70664) and in [MCPE-35991](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-35991)

Comment: Yeah my world was on peaceful I must have switched it when I was going through my setting by mistake, appreciate your help

Comment: @LukeJohnson please mark this answer as accepted if it was useful